# Azure build pipeline: dotnet build fails with: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, specflow

The build pipeline, using the task *dotnet build* started to fail, as the Build Engine version changed from 16.4.0+ to 16.5.0+ recently.

The nuget package *SpecFlow* has a dependency to the library *TechTalk.SpecFlow*.

Exception looks like:

```
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\specflow.tools.msbuild.generation\3.1.89\build\SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.targets(93,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Investigations I did (which didn't help):

- Upgrading the version of SpecFlow to latest
- Downgrading the version of SpecFlow to the first with 3.1
- Explicitly adding the assembly *TechTalk.SpecFlow* to the project
- Using a self hosted build Agent

  - In the file system *TechTalk.SpecFlow* was available in version 3.1.0.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [issue with .NET SDK 3.1.200](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1912).

As a workaround, **you can stay at .NET SDK 3.1.102 until it's fixed** (in .NET SDK, SpecFlow, or both).

Additional info:

https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/1912
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4404#issuecomment-599768237

Comment: In my case, I added `-nodeReuse:false` and that resolved my issue.